# Multiple data set plotting with matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

this might be really a simple question for most of you guys using matplotlib. Please help me out. I want to plot two array like [1,2,3,4] and [4,5,6,7] versus time in a same plot. I am trying to use matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date but couldn't figure out how to do it. It seems to me that only one trend can be plotted with plot_date in one plot.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 13):

To use plot date with multiple trends, it's easiest to call it multiple times. For example:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Generate Data
time = mdates.drange(datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1), 
                     datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1),
                     datetime.timedelta(days=10))
y1 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(time.size) - 0.5)
y2 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(time.size) - 0.5)

# Plot things...
fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot_date(time, y1, 'b-')
plt.plot_date(time, y2, 'g-')

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternately you can use a single `plot` (rather than `plot_date`) call and then call `plt.gca().xaxis_date()`, if you'd prefer. `plot_date` just calls `plot` and then `ax.xaxis_date()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. I have one more question though. What if I want to add multiple scale for each of the data in y-axis? I am not asking about adding one secondary axis but different scale for different trends which can be placed vertically.

Comment: Do you just mean subplots? http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/ganged_plots.html

Comment: Joe, thanks for reply. I don't mean subplots. I mean the same graph with multiple scale for each trend.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that this is essentially what subplots do. You just need to hide the boundaries between them. This is a horizontal example, instead of stacking along the y-axis: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xllnj.png  but the idea is the same.  (That example plot is from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326360/python-matplotlib-probability-plot-for-several-data-set/6339311#6339311 )  If that's not what you had in mind, have a look at `twinx`, but I don't think twinx is what you're wanting from your description.

Comment: Hi, How can I mark the lines, like Green = "aaaa", blue="bbbb"