# panda plot multiple lines base on a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe like this

```
timestamp|type|value_1|value_2

t1|A|v1|v2

t2|B|v3|v4

t3|C|v5|v6

t4|A|v7|v8
```

I would like to plot a graph with 6 lines each type and value
for example

```
type A - value_1
type A - value_2

type B - value_1
type B - value_2

type C - value_1
type C - value_2
```

thanks,

it is like doing this

```
A = df[df["type"] == A]

A.plot(x="time", y=["value_1", "value_2"])
```

do this for three types
and combine those 6 lines on the same graph

Comment: Can i help you with formatting?

Comment: anf for answer, do you need `df.set_index('type').plot()` if `value_1` and `value_2` are numbers?

Comment: I am trying to formatting the table..

Comment: yes, value_1 and value_2 are both numbers

Comment: You need 4 spaces for correct formatting.

Comment: I dont understand 6 lines :(

Comment: group by types and plot value_1 as one line and value_2 as another line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139461/discussion-between-jezrael-and-cynric4sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can reshape `DataFrame` to columns and then `plot`:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('type').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['timestamp','g', 'type']).unstack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

df.plot()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the plotting goes I recommend you check out:
[MatPlotLib: Multiple datasets on the same scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270301/matplotlib-multiple-datasets-on-the-same-scatter-plot) and [Multiple data set plotting with matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340547/multiple-data-set-plotting-with-matplotlib-pyplot-plot-date) , as well as [this tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/users/pyplot_tutorial.html).

For the selection of data to plot I recommend the section "selection by label" in the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). I suppose you could store the values from your corresponding columns / rows in some temporary variables `x1 - xn` and `y1 - yn` and then just plot all the pairs, which could look something like:

```
xs = sheet.loc[<appropriate labels>]
ys = sheet.loc[<appropriate labels>]
for i in range(len(xs)):
   plt.plot(xs[i],ys[i],<further arguments>)
plt.show()
```

In your case, just accessing the 'values' label might not be sufficient, as only every n'th element of that column seams to belong to any given type. in[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list) you can see how you can get a new list with only the appropriate values inside. Basically something like:

```
allXs = sheet.loc['v1']
xsTypeA = allXs[1::4]
...
```

hope that helps.